# Example with .queue() & .dequeue() to do with $.queue() & $.dequeue()

Tags: javascript, jquery, queue

I have done an animation using `animate()`, `queue()`, and `dequeue()`. I have read that jquery has - `jquery.queue()` or `$.queue()` and `jquery.dequeue()` or `$.dequeue()`. Can someone help me these new terms with the help of this example, making changes and using - `$.queue()` and `$.dequeue()` ? Thanks ...

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <button id=but1>Click</button>
    <div id=div1 style="width:50px;height:50px;position:relative;background:pink;">Hi</div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#but1').click(function() {
                $('#div1')
                    .animate({
                        left: "+=300px"
                    }, 3000)
                    .queue(function() {
                        $(this).html("Hello")
                            .css('background', 'red')
                            .css('width', '400px')
                            .dequeue();
                    })
                    .animate({
                        top: "+=500px"
                    }, 1000)
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This question makes no sense, have you seen http://api.jquery.com/jquery.queue/?

Comment: `jQuery.queue` and `$.queue` are the same. Do you maybe mean [jQuery.queue](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.queue/) and [jQuery.fn.queue](https://api.jquery.com/queue/)? I do agree with Liam though that your question does not make sense.

Comment: Difference between .queue() and $.queue()

Answer (score 1):

queue and dequeue operates on selector. any function that doesn't need html element will work with $. like $.ajax()

Comment: jQuery and $ is same thing, jQuery is preferred if you have $ conflicts.